# Getting error on GoogleDataTransport class on xcode9.4 when adding firebase crashlytics pod

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, xcode9

[image]I did pod install for firebase/crashlytics. Now getting error like this on xcode 9.4. I have xcode 11.3 also, on which it works fine.

Comment: Don't use xcode9.4? You can't submit apps built with it anyway

Comment: we are not going for submitting on appstore.

Comment: You could try and use an older version of the pods, but really just move on. You are trying to use new code with a 2 year old compiler. There are swift version changes, catalyst support, iOS version changes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest Firebase release (6.24.0) requires at least Xcode 10.3.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

You would need to go back to an earlier Firebase version for Xcode 9.

Search for Xcode to get more specifics in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios).

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. Im moving to xcode 11. Have some UI changes on xcode 11. That is why I was checking if I can stay on same xcode for some more time. (Y)